# Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded

Tags: fonts, python-docx

I'm going to save a docx to pdf file:

doc = word.Documents.Open(input_file)
doc.SaveAs(output_file, FileFormat=17)

If a do the same action by simple using the "File > SaveAs > .pdf" on Microsoft Word i actually have to remove the flag "Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded" (inside the pdf format option) in order to generate a text-searchable pdf file (See attached image).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYSA3.png)

Is there a way to do the same operation (removing the flag) by python-docx?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, i've now added the question at the end of the post. Thanks